# Pass class attribute as parameter of a function of that class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the title indicates, I am trying to pass an attribute of my class as a parameter for a function of that same class. In the example below, the functionality of `print_top_n()` would be to print `self.topn` by default, but the function could also be called with a different value if need be. Is this a Python (or general programming) foul or is there a way to do this?

```
>>> class Example():
    def __init__(self, topn=5):
        self.topn = topn
    def print_top_n(self, n=self.topn):
        print n



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    class Example():
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 4, in Example
    def print_top_n(self, n=self.topn):
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The methods are created when the class is created, and the default values are set when the method is created (See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)) -- They aren't re-evaluted when the function is called.  In other words, this all happens long before `self` has been created (Hence the `NameError`).

The typical approach is to use a sentinel value that you can check inside of `print_top_n` (`None` is the most common).

```
def print_top_n(self, n=None):
    n = self.topn if n is None else n
    print n
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a marker object. This is a better pattern than `n=None`  (depending on the actual intent of your api) because it will work even if someone passes `n=None` intentionally.

```
marker = object()

class Example:
    def __init__(self, topn=5):
        self.topn = topn

    def print_top_n(self, n=marker):
        if n is marker:
            n = self.topn
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

No; default values are evaluated when the function is defined, so there *is* no object yet to perform an attribute access on. You use a sentinel value instead:

```
def print_top_n(self, n=None):
    if n is None:
        n = self.topn
    print n
```